# Matrix with linearly dependent columns

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there an example of a $3\times 3$ matrix $M = [v_{1}\, v_{2}\, v_{3}]$ (where $v_{i}$ are $3 \times 1$ vectors) such that $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}$ are linearly dependent however if we have $av_{i} + bv_{j} = 0$ then $a, b = 0$ for each $(i, j)$ pair?

Answer (score 1):

Yes:
$$v_1 = (1,0,0)$$
$$v_2 = (1,1,0)$$
$$v_2 = (0,1,0)$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $v_1=[1,2,3]$, $v_2=[3,2,1]$ and $v_3=[4,4,4]$. Clearly the three vectors are dependent. However it is trivial to check that pairwise they are independent.

Answer (score 0):

In general, any three vectors that span a two dimensional space, but such that there is no vector a multiple of another.

For a subset of two such vectors will still span a two dimensional space, hence be linearly independent.

Both other answers fall in this category.